# Adding styles to django.forms controls using Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in my HTML page which I am generating using Django's forms.Form class. I would like to apply styles to the html controls that get generated using Bootstrap. I found that Bootstrap applies styles to the form controls if they have certain class attribute e.g. `form-control`. I am including the form object in my template using `form.as_p` directive. Since there are no explicit html controls that I write in my html page, I don't know how to include the class attribute so that the styles are applied. Can you please help me solve this problem so that I can apply the Bootstrap styles to my form controls?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it with the widget. For example:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Search'}))
```

Another example using a `ModelForm`:

```
class SearchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SearchField
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {
            'name' = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

Comment: I have declared the fields of my form using 'model=MyModel' statement in the Meta class of the form class. How do I add the attributes in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to handle this is using [crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms).

Comment: That would be my answer to. Don't be a fool, use a tool :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the widget's class in the `Form`'s `__init__` like the following.
This is useful when you have a `ModelForm` and you don't want to override the default widgets or fields.

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

    class Meta:
        model = SearchQuery
        fields = ('q',)
```